# Qt static library in windows phone 8.1 application

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, qt5

I have a Qt static library which I have linked to windows runtime component. I am using the runtime component in a windows 8.1 application. The whole set up compiles fine but if I use Qt types (like QString) in the Qt static library, the windows application crashes with the below error:

An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in SampleApp.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

If I remove Qt types from static library and use only standard C++ types (int, wstring) the application works fine and does not crash.

Appreciate any help on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution to the issue.

Turns out windows app was not able to find Qt5Core.dll. The only solution to this issue I could find is to manually add this dll to windows app project in visual studio (Right click on project -> Add existing item) with 'Copy to output directory' property set to 'Copy if newer/Copy always'.